# How can i create a vertical gallery in html and css

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a ecommerce store in php, my php code is working perfectly, but my products are arranged vertically, and i want them arranged horizontally.

I tried float: left, display:inline... But it doesnt work

i would like to see 4 products on the same line.

My php code(ignore the language)

```
<?php
  $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                           FROM  `livros-desporto` ");

     if(isset($_POST['buscar'])){
    $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                             FROM `livros-desporto`
                             where name like '%".$_POST['buscar']."%'");
     }

      while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))  
      {
          $id = $linha['ID'];
          $modelo = $linha['Model'];
          $nome = $linha['Name'];
          $categoria = $linha['Category'];
          $imagem = $linha['Image'];
          $manufactura = $linha['Manufacturer'];
          $preco = $linha['Price'];
          $quantidade = $linha['quantity']
         // $adicionar = '<a href="carrinho.php?id='.$linha['ID']
             //.'"title="'.$linha['ID'].'">
        //  Adicionar </a>'   
   ?>
```

My HTML code

```
<div class="fade1">

<div class="produtos">

<li>            
    <p><?php echo $nome ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $imagem ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $categoria ?></p>
</li>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php
      }

  ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: If your PHP is ok, then do not post it, and delete the PHP tag. Let us see your CSS instead, and put a CSS tag to your post to attract the CSS gurus. Use edit to do so.

Comment: There is an error in the format of your html. List elements <li> should be inside <ul> tags. If you are going to make lists in horizontal manner w/o bullets, you should set the css list-style property to none and display as inline

Answer (score 0):

```
display:inline-block;
```

can be used to display your `div` or `li` elements horizontally. If you create a container of a fixed width, and your product containers are roughly 1/4 of that width, then they should wrap to the next line after every 4th item.

paste your css code, or an example fiddle, for more help.